# How to update the data between parent to child

Tags: angular

I am able to pass the data from parent to child on template binding(on ngInit). but how can i share the same data when its updated at parent component. Is there is observable to share(from parent to child component) the updated data without involving service?

I tried the template with
`<child-template *ngIf='data' [data]='data'></child-template>`

But this passes data only for 1 time. what if data gets updated in parent component?

Comment: take a look on https://angular.io/guide/observables
there is also an explanation here on how to use observables and subjects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Output` in the **ChildComponent**

```
// ChildComponent 
@Output() OutputEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

// trigger the event to 'emit' the output event
onClick(): void {
    this.OutputEvent.emit('the string to be emitted');
}
```

**ParentComponent**

```
// ParentComponent view
<child-component (OutputEvent)="receiveValue($event)">

// ParentComponent controller
receiveValue($event){
    // $event is from ChildComponent = 'the string to be emitted'
}
```

**Big Guns**

Sometimes updates will not occur as you expect. Brush up on `ngOnChanges` to monitor for updates.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if ('varName' in changes) {
        // console.log(this.varName);
        // console.log(changes.varName.previousValue);
        // console.log(changes.varName.firstChange); // etc
    }
}
```

**Two-Way Data Binding**

I stay away from it. [I've asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154917/angular-two-way-data-binding-and-watching-for-changes-in-parent-component) about it that no one seems to know the answers too regarding how to watch for its changes in the parent.

If you think you need 2WDB think about *leveraging a service* to sync the data via observable patterns.

**CLARIFIED QUESTION:**
The question was clarified to parent to child cmmunication. Which is much easier. Using only @Input you can pass the child component a value with simple data-binding in the parent's view.

**ChildComponent**

```
// This property is bound using its original name.
@Input() bankName: string;

// this property value is bound to a different property name
// when this component is instantiated in a template.
@Input('originator') bankName: string;
```

**ParentComponent view**

```
<child-component [bankName]="parentComponentClassVariable"></child-component>
or send a string
<child-component [bankName]="'some string here'"></child-component>
```

Comment: Your answer is to share data from child to parent. I am looking for parent to child.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in question.. . I am looking for how can i pass the updated data from parent tto child. Will events work from parent to child?

Comment: Updated with parent to child communication which is much simpler anyways.

Comment: After i pass the data to child, and the data in parent gets change, I am unable to get the updated data to child...This is my problem

Comment: So that's what I tried to touch on regarding updates and occasionally needing `ngOnChanges`. If you aren't triggering Angular's change detection you sometimes need to manually trigger it or watch `OnChanges`. Are you getting updated values there when values from the parent change?

Comment: Ok got it., `ngOnChanges` should be in child component?

Comment: Yes it will watch for changes. I have these issues too quite often. It's a quirk in Angular to get changes syncing nicely. If component to component communications becomes larger than say 2 back-forth setups I create a service.

Comment: Yea.. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, if you need more help please reach out. Please accept this as the answer to your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

angular update data in child when it was updated in parent. You need to change link for object(reassiagn data, create new object). if you need to detect changes use ngOnChanges lifecycle hook

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple approch that update parent `val` property from the child component by using property binding. In this approach, we did not have any method or listener in parents to listen to the child emitted event.

1. Parent Component

   ```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core'


     @Component({
       selector:'parent-component',
       templateUrl:`<child-component [(value)]="val"> </child-component>        
                   <span> {{ val }}  </span>`,
       styles:[]
     })


     class ParentComponent {
       public val:string = ""; 
     }
   ```

2. Child component

   ```
     import {Component,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

     @Component({
       selector:'child-component',
       templateUrl:`<input type="text" [value]="value" (input)="updateChange($event.target.value)"/>`,
       styles:[]
     })

     class ChildComponent{

       @Input() value:string;
       //The change suffix is most important in @output function 
       @Output() valueChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>()

        updateChange(value){
           this.value = value
           this.valueChange.emit(value)
         }
     }
   ```

Comment: the child doesn't need to emit anything. lets say parent sends value to child and then parent value is updated. but the child doesn't have new data. child has old data only. that was the question. How does the child gets updated data from parent.